# Get Pandas DataFrame entry by index along with subsequent N rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to extract records from a Pandas DataFrame indexed by dates. Ideally, I would like to specify a date, and be able to extract that record along with the following N records, regardless of their index.

So, given something like this:

```
In[54]: dat.master_data[['GLD']].ix['2013-11-01':'2013-11-07']
Out[54]: 
               GLD
Date              
2013-11-07  126.16
2013-11-06  127.20
2013-11-05  126.56
2013-11-04  126.81
2013-11-01  126.95
```

I would like to be able to specify '2013-11-01' and retrieve the next N rows without explicitly including another date.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: One way would be to do `dat.master_data[['GLD']].ix['2013-11-01':].head(N)` this would retrieve all rows from `2013-11-01` onwards but jus the first `N` rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to call `head` on the slice of your df:

```
In [5]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':randn(100)})
df.loc[75:].head(5)
Out[5]:
           a
75 -0.496766
76  0.666981
77  1.686994
78  0.175461
79 -0.495093
```